# php cuRL response "unable to transcode data stream audio/flac -> audio/x-float-array" - IBM Watson Speech to text API

Tags: php, curl, ibm-watson

I don't know much about how to use cURL.I am trying to convert Speech to Text using IBM Watson API. When I try to convert it without using parameters(Translate English 
 Audio File), I get a response without any error.

But when I add

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
      'model'=>'ja-JP_NarrowbandModel'
))
```

It returns

```
{ "code_description": "Bad Request", "code": 400, "error": "unable to 
transcode data stream audio/flac -> audio/x-float-array " }
```

I am not sure if there is an issue in my Syntax or something else is going wrong there.

I read docs from : https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/speech-to-text/http.html#http

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
$file = file_get_contents('audio-file.flac');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $file);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'apikey' . ':' . 'MY_API_HERE');
$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: audio/flac';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
'model'=>'ja-JP_NarrowbandModel'
));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` twice, once with the content of your file and a second time with an array containing `'model'=>'ja-JP_NarrowbandModel'`.

According to [the documentation](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/speech-to-text/http.html#HTTP-basic), you can pass the model as a query parameter.

Try something like this (not tested):

```
<?php

$file = file_get_contents('audio-file.flac');

$url = 'https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize';
$model = 'ja-JP_NarrowbandModel';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url . '?model=' . $model);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $file);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'apikey' . ':' . 'MY_API_HERE');

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: audio/flac';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
print_r($result);
```